# Quicklinks behavior difference in two laptop

Tags: windows-10

I have two laptops, both latest Windows 10 Professional. I have a "quicklinks" toolbar set up, and the contents of that folder is located on a NAS and is used by both laptops. I keep the laptops in sync as far as software so all the shortcuts work as expected.

Within the toolbar quicklinks I have a folder with additional shortcuts. On laptop #1, the "original" laptop, when I click on this sub-folder, a menu pops upward and I can choose a shortcut.

However in laptop #2 when I click on this folder, and entirely separate explorer window opens to that folder.

I cannot find a property or setting which controls this behavior.

Any ideas?